# Proving a function by induction

Tags: functions, induction, fibonacci-numbers

Let $f(n)$ be the function defined by

$$
f(n) = \frac 1{\sqrt{5}} \left[ 
\left(1+\sqrt{5}\over2\right)^n- 
\left(1-\sqrt{5}\over2\right)^n
\right]
$$

How do you prove that $f(n) = f(n+2) - f(n+1)$ for all $n = 0, 1, 2, ...$ ?

Comment: You can also prove that $f(n)$ is the $n$-th Fibonacci number, which is essentially what you're saying (I'm assuming you meant $f(n)=f(n+2)-f(n+1)$). This probably simplifies things.

Comment: The `$`s are your friends

Comment: What do you know about induction?  What have you tried?  This website is for answering questions, not giving lectures.  Do you *have* to use induction, or can other approaches be used?

Comment: Thanks for the editing aid @Omnomnomnom

Comment: I know that you have to start from the base case by proving the given statement for the first natural number. Then, from step case, it needs to be proven that the given statement for any one natural number implies the given statement for the next natural number @DanielV

Comment: @iterence Show us how far along you've gotten with that, otherwise this question will probably be closed.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** note that $x = \frac 12 (1 \pm \sqrt{5})$ satisfies
$$
x^2 - x - 1=0
$$
or, more generally,
$$
x^n = x^{n+2} - x^{n+1}
$$